# Selecting the right nodes when using LINQ to XML

Tags: linq-to-xml

I have an xml file that another program is using. It is pointing to the path of a couple ini-files and I am interested in extracting them. They are the `<add>`-tags with a `key="config1"` (or cofig2, etc) under the `<appSettings>`-tag. Here is a sample file I want to read.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <!-- Comment -->
    <add key="config1" value="\\server1\software\pgrTool\Standard.ini.xml" />
    <!--<add key="config2" value="C:\HeadQuarter\PgrTool.xml" />-->
    <add key="config2" value="\\server1\software\pgrTool\Standard.xml" />
    <add key="hide-REM" value="no" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I want the nodes

```
<add key="config1" value="\\server1\software\pgrTool\Standard.ini.xml" />
<add key="config2" value="\\server1\software\pgrTool\Standard.xml" />
```

I tried the following Linq query:

```
var iniman = from c in XElement.Load(@"C:\Program Files\pgrTool\pgrTool.exe.config").Elements("add")
                         where c.Attribute("key").Value.StartsWith("config")
                         select c.Attribute("value");
```

but it didn't return any nodes. How can I specifically select these lines and any other config?-lines using LINQ to XML?

**edit**: I tried this

```
var configs = var iniman2 = from c in XElement.Load(@"C:\Program Files\pgrTool\pgrTool.exe.config").Elements("configuration").Elements("appSettings")
                          where c.Attribute("key").Value.StartsWith("config")
                          select c.Attribute("value");
```

And that didn't return any nodes either.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why are you using `XElement.Load` instead of `XDocument.Load`? Your XML file is clearly an XML document, so you should load it to `XDocument` instance.

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Program Files\pgrTool\pgrTool.exe.config");
```

And now back to the query. Your first one didn't return any values, because `Elements` method only looks over direct children of current element. The second one didn't work either, because you tried to get `<appSettings>` elements instead of `<add>`.

Your query should be:

```
var paths = from add in doc.Root.Element("appSettings").Elements("add")
            where ((string)add.Attribute("key")).StartsWith("config")
            select (string)add.Attribute("value");
```